# What the "+<NUMBER>" means at the end of each C++ trace line?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, backtrace, line-numbers

My android app crashes on Google side and it prints me backtrace like following:

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000001fc90  /data/app/com.inthemoon.normalvoicerecorder-1/lib/arm64/libmp3lame.so (L3psycho_anal_vbr+5324)
    #01 pc 00000000000185b4  /data/app/com.inthemoon.normalvoicerecorder-1/lib/arm64/libmp3lame.so (lame_encode_mp3_frame+844)
```

What does numbers "+5324" and "+844" mean heare? Can I decode line numbers from these numbers, i.e. determine, where in code exception was raised?

Comment: Current executing instructions on each stack frame. Byte offset from the  known symbols (exported function names). You can decode line numbers instead of byte offsets if you have debug symbols.

Comment: In the bracket, you have the function and offset. If you can disassemble the binary, you can inspect and see the exact instruction (all but the final one will probably refer to a function call). You can also set a breakpoint at that location in GDB.

Comment: Does this output imply the system didn't had debug symbols?

Comment: can't `addr2line` give you the line where 000000000001fc90 happened?